# Clistview With Pagination in Yii

Tags: yii, pagination, clistview

I don't get along with pagination for one of my CListView. In my controller I fetch records to a CActivedataProvider by using a criteria and I pass that data provider to my CListView. I can see that database fetch is working fine since I can see all records in my CListView if I don't apply pagination.

The problem begins when pagination is turned on. I would like to see all records on a separate page with a pagination at the bottom.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Here is what I have in my controller:

```
if(isset($_POST['Lista']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Lista'];
        }

        $egyedi_osszetevo_idk = Lista::getEgyediOsszetevoIdk($model->datum_tol, $model->datum_ig);


        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->addInCondition("id", $egyedi_osszetevo_idk);
        $count = EtelOsszetevo::model()->count($criteria);

        $pages=new CPagination($count);
        $pages->pageSize=1;
        $pages->applyLimit($criteria);

        $dataProviderEgyediOsszetevok = new CActiveDataProvider('EtelOsszetevo', array(
                        'criteria'=>$criteria,
                        'pagination'=>$pages,
                ));

        $this->render('view',array('model'=>$model,
                                   'egyedi_osszetevo_idk'=>$dataProviderEgyediOsszetevok,
                                   ));
```

Here is my CListView in my view file:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$egyedi_osszetevo_idk,
        'itemView'=>'_view',
));
```

Comment: @Samuel 1.) I would like to use CListView's default pagination. 2.) I meant that I would like to see one record per page. Thanks!

Comment: @Samuel The problem is that when I set the pagination of my data provider and I limit pagination to show only 1 record per page, CListView can't find my next record when I click on next page button.